# Powder to prevent foam in egg white protein?

Tags: egg-whites

I have a bunch of egg white protein powder to take as a supplement. Only when I mix it in a shaker bottle, it foams up. Reading the answers about souffles I got the idea that if the egg yolk prevents foaming, and that yolks contain lecithin--that must be what the soy lecithin is for in the commercial egg proteins which don't foam up at all. But that didn't work. What is a powder--natural if possible--that I can add so that it mixes like the store bought stuff?

Comment: Have you tried a bit of fat? Like a drop of vegetable oil?

Comment: @Jolenealaska I was hoping for something in powder form, so that I can prepare this all up front. Can fat come in a powder?

Comment: Yes it can, but I can't think of a "straight fat" in a powdered form at the moment. Check this out though http://www.molecularrecipes.com/techniques/converting-high-fat-liquids-powder/, at least in the meantime.

Comment: You may have less foamy results simply by mixing it by stirring rather than shaking.

Comment: I don't think that there can be a powder for that. The physical properties of a foam inhibitor will point to compounds which are unlikely to make a usable powder (too soft at room temperature). Not an answer, because maybe there is a chemist out there who knows the perfect class of molecules which is separate of the fats and waxes I am thinking of, and still inhibits foaming.

Comment: @Jeremy - fat can come in a powder - powdered butter is a thing, for example, used for camping or unrefrigerated storage - though I don't know if it will still work the same way on foaming.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a ["food grade" antifoam agent](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=Lh5&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&q=%22food%20grade%22%20antifoam%20agent&oq=%22food%20grade%22%20antifoam%20agent&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i22i30.51354.65046.0.65892.10.10.0.0.0.0.280.1626.0j8j2.10.0....0...1c.1.32.serp..0.10.1625.O4ibW4IYdqw). A brief look at the linked search results shows [antifoam powders look to be mostly silicone based](https://www.midwestsupplies.com/anti-foam-agent-powder.html?utm_medium=feeds&utm_source=google&gdftrk=gdfV24959_a_7c1306_a_7c6184_a_7c8328&gclid=CKzkpbzdursCFclcMgodQAIAoQ). They may or may not work for your heavy protein foam.

Comment: Reading up on the silicone based antifoam powders it seems like something I can't do at home, i.e.: how do I ensure 5PPM? Is this something that commercial products don't have to list? The stuff I'm comparing it with has this ingredient list: Egg Albumen, Cocoa, Artificial Flavor, Lecithin, Sucralose.

Comment: @Jeremy are you using cocoa powder in yours? It may have enough fat to cut down the foam somewhat.

Comment: @sourd'oh, I am and though it helps, it is still super foamy. I have to drink it, then put more water to pick up all the foam. I usually stop there because I get lazy, but it is still foamy the second time. I also tried putting some olive oil as someone mentioned above, but that didn't do much.

Answer (score 0):

You had the solution in your question. Add a hard boiled egg with your protein shake and blend it up in your blender. The egg yolk will lessen the foaming of the powder. It works, that's what I do, and I use 15 grams of egg white protein powder. Stay away from soy lecithin.

Answer (score 0):

I put the protein powder in a 2 cup glass measuring cup. Then I add the water slowly, 1 or 2 Tbsp at a time, and stir whith a spoon. The egg white protein powder clumps as you stir, but keep adding water and stirring; it will eventually mix. This process still produces a little bit of foam, but not nearly so much as using a whisk.